# HyperX Headset not working

Tags: sound, 20.04, headset

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Apple Mac, however I realised that my headset does not work. I tried alsamixer but it didn't work. I tested the headset on my iPhone and it worked perfectly fine. Please help, as I have a few online meetings to attend in the near future.

Comment: Welcome! It is good to mention how your headset is connected, and what exactly does not work. Is it a microphone input issue? sound output? both? This would really help other users understand your situation better.

Comment: It is connected but the Input and sound output is not working